# Minimial test of database connectivity in django

Tags: django

I'm writing a quick little test view that I can `GET` every few minutes to check that my application and database servers are online and functioning.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseServerError
from my_app.models import Model

def test(request):
    '''
    Returns a HttpResponse to prove the application/db servers work
    '''
    if request.method == "GET":
        #test database access
        count = Model.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).count()
        if count:
            return HttpResponse("OK")

    return HttpResponseServerError("Error")
```

Is there a more minimal inbuilt database query that I could do to test that the db server is working and takling to the app server, without having to do a fake one like I did above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import django connections and check with your databases:

```
from django.db import connections
try:
    cursor = connections['default'].cursor()
except OperationalError:
    return HttpResponseServerError("Error")
else:
    return HttpResponse("OK")
return HttpResponseServerError("Error")
```

[Documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/#using-raw-cursors-with-multiple-databases)

Comment: Thanks, I added exception handling in case anyone tries to copy-paste and doesn't realise `.cursor()` will throw an error that needs to be handled.